# Binding user input data to AngularJS object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im working on a project where I input a user's Id, first name and last name. Once input, I create a user object which is stored inside the logins array.

What I'm trying to do is display each new user as the next item in an unordered list each time the login button is clicked. Right now, I'm trying to get the user input from the text boxes, this works for the first item, until I try to clear the text boxes. How can I correctly bind my input to the user object while still being able to display each new user? I.e, add more than one user and have them both show up. They seem to be added to the array fine, but I can't figure out where the display is going wrong.

I'm thinking that because of the way I'm trying to get the data input to the text boxes, my variables are set as I enter them, but I'm not sure what else I can try. Quite new to angular. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        id: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
    };
    $scope.logins = [];
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logins.push($scope.user);
        console.log($scope.logins);
    };

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input id="id" ng-model="user.id"></input>
    <input id="first" ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
    <input id="last" ng-model="user.lastName"></input>

    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="login in logins" >{{user.id + ', ' + user.firstName + ', ' + user.lastName}}</li>
    </ul>    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error your getting and the version of angular?

Comment: I just noticed I'm still using 1.2.13 from an old file that I thought I could modify. I should have been using the most recent version. Now I'm more lost than I thought I was.

Comment: no worries, we can make this work. whats the error?

Comment: The code I have posted works fine but if you clear the text boxes the list display breaks. With the version updated nothing is working at all apparently

Comment: please include the code you have to clear the text boxes.

Comment: I've been manually clearing them thus far. I was assuming that once the values were pushed to the array and then displayed, clearing the text boxes wouldn't delete the values that had been input. If that makes any sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127577/discussion-between-alphapilgrim-and-jeremy-stone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add same object (duplicate) that you have used for repeater,
you want some like this,

check below or check on https://jsbin.com/pulinetari/1/edit?html,console,output

check

```
$scope.logins.push({id:$scope.user.id, firstName: $scope.user.firstName, lastName: $scope.user.lastName});
```

you need to create new object to add on array, which uses by repeater.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        id: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
    };
    $scope.logins = [];
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logins.push({id:$scope.user.id, firstName: $scope.user.firstName, lastName: $scope.user.lastName});
        console.log($scope.logins);
    };
 $scope.selectUser= function(user){
  $scope.user = user;
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input id="id" ng-model="user.id"></input>
    <input id="first" ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
    <input id="last" ng-model="user.lastName"></input>

    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="login in logins" ng-click="selectUser(login)">{{login.id + ', ' + login.firstName + ', ' + login.lastName}}</li>
    </ul>    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```